# Insufficient Entropy cryptiles Error resolve

Tags: npm, hapi, npm-audit

I have warning showing `**Insufficient Entropy**` error for `hapi@16.6.2`

```
Module: cryptiles
Published: November 1st 2018
Reported by: Microsoft Vulnerability Research
CWE-331
CVE-2018-1000620
Vulnerable: >=3.1.0 <3.1.3 || >=4.0.0 <4.1.2
Patched: >=3.1.3 <4.0.0 || >=4.1.2
CVSS: 2
```

In latest version of `hapi >16.6.2`, `cryptiles` dependency is removed. But hapi major version is not compatible with the old version.

How can I resolve these vulnerability warning by updating the **specific 
subpackage** versions. Or there is any other approach. npm audit could not
able to fix my problem.

I have tried runing `npm audit fix` but it could not resolve this issue.

Comment: Or those who stumbled upon this question. It is not a good practice to update only specific packages within a library. It is better to raise an issue in respective repository in whose dependency you have vulnerability.